# Node-Sass compile multiple files in a single directory to one file

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

I need to compile multiple scss files into a single css file using node-sass.

My structure looks like this:

```
/
  /scss
    app.scss
    /components
      header.scss
  /css
    app.css
```

In my app.scss file I import all my other files. So watching just that file doesn't work like this example I tried:

```
"watch": "node-sass -w scss/app.scss css/app.css"
```

It did work as long as I put all the code in that file and didn't import anything else or manually compiled that each time, but the watching didn't work.

So I tried this as well to no avail:

```
"watch": "node-sass -wr scss/* app.css"
```

Comment: Try using grunt https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-concat-css

Comment: I have to use node-sass so unfortunately that's not an option.

Comment: @robertmylne convert the header.scss to _header.scss. Sass is compiling header.scss as header.css from your NPM script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `onchange` npm package. You can watch globs and run scripts when any of them change.

```
"watch": "onchange 'scss/**/*.scss' -- npm run compile",
"compile": "node-sass scss/app.scss css/app.css"
```

Comment: I get the following error:

'onchange' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: Ok this works, needs the onchange npm package. On windows needs to use escaped double quotes.